# CPUs usage 100%

Tags: 14.04, cpu

System is an Atom(MSI Wind Notebook) that was upgraded to 14LTS from 12LTS. Both CPUs are running @ 100%. System Monitor doesn't show anthing but 6-0 % usages. Some spikes of the xringd, compiz, munin and kworker appear and then dissappear.
Also, I'd like to remove the bloatware that came w/ 14LTS(identica, AIM, Salute, Yahoo, Jabber, and Flicker).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem  after a downgrade to 14.04 from 14.10

I downloaded from here :

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0.6-linux

and the compiz CPU % went completely normal

Comment: It would have been helpful to explain what was at this link, as it is now dead, making your answer useless.